# Android: how to know which button was clicked inside "onActivityResult" method

Tags: android

I have two buttons, both of them does barcode scanning. Once it returns from scanning, I want to know which button the user clicked so I can take different path on "onActivityResult" method. How do I do that?

I can find out which button was clicked inside onClick() method but that won't help.

```
public class ReaderActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button scan_btn, verifyButton;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_reader);
        scan_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scan_btn);
        verifyButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonVerify);
        final Activity activity = this;
        scan_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(activity);
                integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.ALL_CODE_TYPES);
                integrator.setPrompt("Scan");
                integrator.setCameraId(0);
                integrator.setBeepEnabled(false);
                integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(false);
                integrator.initiateScan();
            }
        });

        verifyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(activity);
                integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.ALL_CODE_TYPES);
                integrator.setPrompt("LINE UP BARCODE WITH SCANNER");
                integrator.setCameraId(0);
                integrator.setBeepEnabled(false);
                integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(false);
                integrator.initiateScan();

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(result != null){
            if(result.getContents()==null){
                Toast.makeText(this, "You cancelled the scanning", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(this, result.getContents(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }
        else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add boolean value inside your activity

eg :

```
private boolean isScanButtonClicked;
```

Use below code

```
 scan_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    isScanButtonClicked = true; // true a scan button clicked
                    IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(activity);
                    integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.ALL_CODE_TYPES);
                    integrator.setPrompt("Scan");
                    integrator.setCameraId(0);
                    integrator.setBeepEnabled(false);
                    integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(false);
                    integrator.initiateScan();
                }
            });


    verifyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    isScanButtonClicked = false; // false as scan button not clicked
                    IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(activity);
                    integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.ALL_CODE_TYPES);
                    integrator.setPrompt("LINE UP BARCODE WITH SCANNER");
                    integrator.setCameraId(0);
                    integrator.setBeepEnabled(false);
                    integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(false);
                    integrator.initiateScan();

                }
```

According to **isScanButtonClicked** value you can perform your action inside onActivityResult()

Hope these help you.

Comment: No it doesn't. I tried similar approach before posting. isScanButtonClicked always stays at your declared value (in this case private boolean isScanButtonClicked means false by default) no matter which button I click - the status is not available in onActivityResult method

Comment: make it static then

Answer (score 0):

You could add some flag/data to **Intent data** return and process this data into **onActivityResult** to get the button clicked in your action, or change the value of **resultCode** to process this result on correct way.

Comment: can you give an example how?

Comment: Are you executing 'startActivityForResult' somewhere?

Comment: No, I am not. I have not started the scanning activity that way.

Comment: Can you post the **initiateScan** method here?

Comment: It is part of the zxing library which I am using. Didn't write that

Comment: Oh yeah, i'm looking here. If you open the **initiateScan** you will see the **putExtra** for some data, you could add a personal **putExtra** with a int code which represents the clicked button and then process the intent data in return of onActivityResult

Comment: I know you can add **putExtra** for an **Intent** object. But initiateScan is part of **IntentIntegrator** object which doesn't have putExtra. So I am confused how to pass that in this case.

Comment: I will try to send you an example

Comment: You looked at initiatescan method? There exists some putExtra lines. You could pass a value for this method and manipulate then inside this method.

Comment: Yes I looked into. But I prefer not to manipulate the library function. If I can do the same instead of calling the initiateScan method that would be good

Comment: Yeah, ok. I'm looking here for a solution.

Comment: There is a createScanIntent() method for IntentIntegrator class which returns an intent. So I can do `IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(activity);` `Intent scanIntent = integrator.createScanIntent();` `scanIntent.putExtra("press", isScanButtonClicked);` `integrator.initiateScan();` This should work and I should be able to read it in onActivityResult but it is still not working.

Comment: Yeah, try this and send me a feedback.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public Button btnOne;
    public Button btnTwo;
    public String btnClicked;

    public static int VALUEONE = 1;
    public static int VALUETWO = 2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnUm = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnUm);
        btnDois = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnDois);

        btnOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               Intent test = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
                btnClicked = "btnOne";
                startActivityForResult(test,VALUEONE);
            }
        });

       btnTwo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               Intent test = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
                btnClicked = "btnTwo";
                startActivityForResult(test,VALUETWO);
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       System.out.println("Btn clicked: " + btnClicked);
  }
```

...........

I try this code in my Android Studio and it works. You made something similar to this?

Comment: I am aware of this approach. But I guess my issue is not this straightforward as I have zxing api etc.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it through get set method

Created a class like below

```
public class myApplication extends Application{

    private String someVariable;

    public String getWhichButton() {
        return someVariable;
    }

    public void setWhichButton(String someVariable) {
        this.someVariable = someVariable;
    }
}
```

Make sure to add `android:name=".myApplication"` in the `<Application>` tag in AndroidManifest. Then in my ReaderActivity during the button click action, I set

```
((myApplication) activity.getApplication()).setWhichButton("scan");
```

OR

```
((myApplication) activity.getApplication()).setWhichButton("Verify");
```

depending on which button I click. On the onActivityResult method I use

```
((myApplication) this.getApplication()).getWhichButton();
```

to retrieve which button was clicked to take action accordingly.

```
public class ReaderActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    private Button scan_btn, verifyButton;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_reader);
        scan_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scan_btn);
        verifyButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonVerify);
        final Activity activity = this;
        scan_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ((myApplication) activity.getApplication()).setWhichButton("scan");

                IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(activity);
                integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.ALL_CODE_TYPES);
                integrator.setPrompt("Scan");
                integrator.setCameraId(0);
                integrator.setBeepEnabled(true);
                integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(false);
                integrator.initiateScan();

            }
        });

        verifyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ((myApplication) activity.getApplication()).setWhichButton("verify");
                IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(activity);
                integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.ALL_CODE_TYPES);
                integrator.setPrompt("LINE UP BARCODE WITH SCANNER");
                integrator.setCameraId(0);
                integrator.setBeepEnabled(true);
                integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(false);
                integrator.initiateScan();

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


        if(result != null){
            if(result.getContents()==null){
                Toast.makeText(this, "You cancelled the scanning", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(this, result.getContents(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                String val = ((myApplication) this.getApplication()).getWhichButton();
                if(val=="scan") {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Scan button pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Verify button pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
}
```